# Store selection in Spotfire Consumer

Tags: spotfire

We try to create a visualization where people with consumer licence could perform some (basic) analysis. They need to perform data selection on subsets of the data, select one data point by subset and then analyze all the selected data points together.  This would be easy using tags, but unfortunately consumer license doesn't support editing of tags, is there a workaround for that?

Longer story:

We work with trial data, one dataset contains 10-200 trials, each has 5-50 assessments, so there is a quite long list of assessments. Our current way of working with Analyst licence is to filter for each trial (this is necessary for selection of best assessment), tag the best assessment, remove the filter from trials and filter for tagged assessments and perform the analysis.

Without tagging our workaround could be: filter for each trial, select best assessment, then notes it's ID on a paper (!), remove filter of trials, then scroll through the list of assessments and manually select all what has been noted on paper. Besides being a lot of extra work, it has a big risk of cancelling selection by accidentally releasing CTRL button during selection.

Is there a way to improve this process?

*(I've asked the [same question](https://community.tibco.com/questions/store-selection-spotfire-consumer) also on Tibco community site, but it seems the community isn't really active there)*

Answer (score 1):

Assuming I'm understanding your situation correctly, this would be my suggestion:

Have a text area with an button labeled 'Append', an input field (multiple Lines), and a Refresh/Continue button.

Have the user filter down to find a trial, mark the selected assessment, and then hit the Append button, with a script similar to the following:

```
from Spotfire.Dxp.Data import *

crossSource = Document.Data.Tables["TrialsAndAssessments"]

rowIndexSet=Document.ActiveMarkingSelectionReference.GetSelection(crossSource).AsIndexSet()
colCurs = DataValueCursor.CreateFormatted(crossSource.Columns["AssessmentID"])


x = Document.Properties["udPreSelectedAssessments"]
#x = ""
if rowIndexSet.IsEmpty != True:
    for row in crossSource.GetRows(rowIndexSet, colCurs):
        #print colCurs.CurrentValue
        if x == "":
            x += colCurs.CurrentValue
        else:
            x += ", " + colCurs.CurrentValue

Document.Properties["udPreSelectedAssessments"] = x
```

After they have appended all the Assessments they want to this list (which they can also manually edit), the user can hit the Refresh/Continue button.  This button can then change a udSelectedAssessments property, linked up to an Information Link which is set to update automatically and not cache, which  will be a stored procedure which parses through your list of AssessmentIDs itself.  (I recommend having a pre property mainly so that you can strip or add apostrophes etc before passing anything to the database)

Refresh/Continue Button:

```
strVals = Document.Properties["udPreSelectedAssessments"]

lst = ""

x = 0
y = 0
z = 0
for letter in strVals:
    if y == 1:
        if letter == " ":
            lst = lst + strVals[x:z] + ", "
            y = 0
        elif letter == ",":
            lst = lst + strVals[x:z] + ", "
            y = 0
        elif letter == "\n":
            lst = lst + strVals[x:z] + ", "
            y = 0
        elif letter == "\r":
            lst = lst + strVals[x:z] + ", "
            y = 0
        elif letter == "'":
            lst = lst + strVals[x:z] + ", "
            y = 0
        elif letter == '"':
            lst = lst + strVals[x:z] + ", "
            y = 0
        elif letter == '\t':
            lst = lst + strVals[x:z] + ", "
            y = 0
    else:
        if letter <> " " and letter <> "," and letter <> "\n" and letter <> "\r" and letter <> "'" and letter <> '"' and letter <> "\t":
            #print letter
            x = z
            y = 1
    z += 1
if y == 1:
    lst = lst + strVals[x:z] 

print lst

Document.Properties["udSelectedAssessments"] = lst
```

Simple T-SQL example:

```
declare @run varchar(max) = '  
  select * from DataTableName where AssessmentID in (' + @AssessmentList + ')'

  execute (@run)
```

EDIT:  This is the method I use for a Data Set that is large and I don't want to take the memory up on the server to cache the whole thing or make the user wait an inordinate period of time for the analytic to open.  If you do NOT have to worry about either of these, because the Data Set is small or you're caching the whole thing anyways to make it easier to choose the correct Assessment, then I recommend the following adjustment.

Append this code to the code provided above for the Refresh Button:

```
lst = lst.upper()
if len(lst) > 0:
    Document.Properties["udSpecialCheck"] = 0
    Document.Properties["udSelectedAssessments"] = lst
else:
    Document.Properties["udSpecialCheck"] = 1
```

Use the original Data Set, but limit the visualization in the Data Expression by the following code:

```
Upper([Assessment]) in (${udSelectedAssessments) or ${udSpecialCheck} = 1
```

Comment: Thanks Chelsea! I'm not confident with programming in Spotfire yet, so will need to try your solution with a colleague. Will come back with questions if necessary.